# Sending multiple parameters to Retrofit Interface call

Tags: android, interface, retrofit, retrofit2

I have a method 'makeFriend(email)' on my node.js server which adds one user with another as a friend using both of their email IDs, as follows
https://fitnessrace.herokuapp.com/users/{emailOfUser}/make_friend/{emailofFriend}

The response from postman is [The Postman successful response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QX9oO.png)

I want to do the same from my Android app as well, where i have an interface defined as

```
public interface RetrofitInterface
{
    //for adding a friend with email
    @PUT("users/{emailOfUser}/make_friend/{emailofFriend}")
    Call<Response> makeFriend(@Path("emailofFriend") String email);
}
```

As you can see there is only  one Parameter that i can pass by a retrofit call as follows

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);
            Call<Response> call = retrofitInterface.makeFriend("emailofFriend");
```

Now my question is how can I pass my 'emailOfUser' to the interface,as I can only send the 'emailofFriend' string through my retrofit call ?
 I have my email saved in the SharedPreference as well, but I am not sure whether I can access it in the Interface.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should Add one More Parameter inside The Method

```
public interface RetrofitInterface
{
    //for adding a friend with email
    @PUT("users/{emailOfUser}/make_friend/{emailofFriend}")
    Call<Response> makeFriend(@Path("emailOfUser") String user,@Path("emailofFriend") String email);
}
```

and Pass Parameter From Here

```
RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);
Call<Response> call = retrofitInterface.makeFriend("User","emailofFriend");
```

Comment: That I understood, my question was how to pass that parameter from my Retrofit Call?

Comment: Check Edited Answer ,I hope You ll Be Well Understood Answer

Comment: Would it work even though the method on the server accepts just 1 parameter?

Answer (score 0):

in your interface your method should be

```
@PUT("users/{emailOfUser}/make_friend/{emailofFriend}")
Call<Response> makeFriend(@Path("emailofUser") String email, @Path("emailOfFriend") String email_friend);
```

and in your call it will become as follows

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);
        Call<Response> call = retrofitInterface.makeFriend(USER_EMAIL_STRING, FRIEND_EMAIL_STRING);
```

hope this helps